# What should I use for a collection of different objects in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, nested-sets

This is illegal in Matlab

```
a = [[1];[2 3]]
```

In languages that allow this, this is called nested arrays.

I found a way of doing the same in Matlab:

```
 a = {[1];[2 3]}
```

What is this called?
How initialize such a variable with a fixed size (say 100) without having to write much code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a cell array.

You initialize it using the command [`cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html)

```
cellArray = cell(3,2); %# this makes a 3-by-2 cell array
```

An alternative way to store collections of different objects is the [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html), which you'd initialize like this

```
myStruct = struct('firstField',1,'secondField',[2 3])
```

The advantage of structs over cells is that the fields are named, which makes it a lot easier to deal with and document. Cells can be very convenient for storing data if you want to manipulate the data often, because you can for example use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) with them. I find myself often using cells to keep data inside a function, but using structures (or objects) to pass data between functions.

Also, if you have a list of numbers and want to distribute them to elements of the cell array, you can use [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html), which puts every element of the array separately into an element of the cell array, or [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html), in case you want to split the array unevenly.

```
a = {1,[2 3]}
```

is equivalent to

```
b = mat2cell([1 2 3],[1 1],[1 2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively I could discover the meaning of the curly brackets by typing

```
help paren
```

Which outputs:

> { }  Braces are used to form cell arrays.  They are similar to
>         brackets [ ] except that nesting levels are preserved.
>         {magic(3) 6.9 'hello'} is a cell array with three elements.
>         {magic(3),6.9,'hello'} is the same thing.
>         {'This' 'is' 'a';'two' 'row' 'cell'} is a 2-by-3 cell array.
>         The semicolon ends the first row. {1 {2 3} 4} is a 3 element
>         cell array where element 2 is itself a cell array.
>
> ```
>  Braces are also used for content addressing of cell arrays.
>   They act similar to parentheses in this case except that the
>   contents of the cell are returned. 
>
>  Some examples:
>      X{3} is the contents of the third element of X.
>      X{3}(4,5) is the (4,5) element of those contents.
>      X{[1 2 3]} is a comma-separated list of the first three
>      elements of X.  It is the same as X{1},X{2},X{3} and makes sense
>      inside [] ,{}, or in function input or output lists (see LISTS).
>
>  You can repeat the content addressing for nested cells so
>   that X{1}{2} is the contents of the second element of the cell
>   inside the first cell of X.  This also works for nested
>   structures, as in X(2).field(3).name or combinations of cell arrays
>   and structures, as in  Z{2}.type(3).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That's a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-42340.html#f16-6840).  Avoid them unless you really need them, because they're a pain to work with, they're much slower, and the syntax is a horrible, inconsistent, bolt-on kludge.